# "Squishing" or "a squish"?

Tags: nouns, gerunds, slang

1. Do you like the squishing?
2. Would you like some squishing?
3. Would you like a squish?

Are these all written correctly? When do you  say *squishing* instead of *squish*, and vice versa?

Comment: Can you please use these in context? One doesn't usually ask someone if they like being squished because it's not a comfortable situation to be in.... You might say "are you getting squished"... but you wouldn't *generally* ask if someone wants to be unless you mean it as a threat... and then you wouldn't ask it this way at all.

Comment: It appears that in the last few years *squish* has picked up some extended meanings, particularly among what we used to call teeny-boppers, and those who have recently been teeny-boppers. One meaning is a sentimental attachment, like a *crush*; another, which I think is operative here, is a *hug* or friendly squeeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take heed of @Catija's comment: *Squish* when the target is a person is similar to, but not as strong as *crush* or *squeeze*.  By default it describes something somewhat unpleasant.

On the off chance this is a playful context, *squeeze* would be far better of a term.

---

Regarding the meaning of the sentences, they are all correct, but have different shades of meaning:

> Do you like the squishing?

The squishing is happening now, or has recently happened, and you are asking someone's opinion on that.  Do not use this if a squishing has not occurred yet.  *Do you like squishing?* is asking someone's opinion on squishing in general.

> Would you like some squishing?

You are offering someone many squishes, or a continuous duration of squishing.

> Would you like a squish?

You are offering someone a single squish.

Comment: Grammatical or not, they still don't really make much sense... from the point of view of a native. :P

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe one would generally use "squishing" outside of the common phrase:

> You're squishing me!

[image: Hamster being squished]

[Squish](http://www.onomatopoeialist.com/squish/) is an [onomatopoetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia) word that comes from the sound made by something being... for lack of a better word... squished.

> Verb
>    - Make a soft squelching sound when walked on or in: “the mud squished under my shoes”.
>
> Noun
>    - A soft squelching sound.

It has, of course, [come to mean](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/squish) the action that causes the noise:

> to crush something

Or, more broadly, it simply means "squeeze"... In fact, in this sense you can replace the vowel sound in "squish" with just about any other and have it work to mean, essentially the same thing:  squash, squeesh (squeeze), squoosh, skwush (uncommon).

In general, it's not a pleasant thing... as you can see from the [synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/squish) here:

[image: Synonyms for "squish"]

If one wishes to ask someone if they like to be **squished** you would most likely use the -ed form, not the -ing.

> 1. Do you like *being squished*?
> 2. Would you like *to be squished*?

As for "Would you like a squish?"... I'm not really sure what you mean by this... the only thing that makes sense is that you're using it as a synonym of "hug".

> 3. Would you like a hug?

Alternatively, if you're asking someone something like

> 1. Do you like *squishing* bugs?
> 2. Would you like to do some squishing of bugs? (very odd sounding but grammatical)

**Now** you can use the gerund form.

Comment: "Why, Mr. Ant! You seem to think that my picnic food has been placed on this blanket in order to feed you and your family! Would you like a squish?"